# Creating mutually referential consts without `get`

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```js
export const foo: Bla {
  prop: [bar, baz]
}

export const bar: Bla {
  prop: [foo, bar]
}

export const baz: Bla {
  prop: [bar, baz]
}
```

But obviously, bar hasn't been defined yet as of the definition of foo, etc, so that doesn't work. I would also like for the prop arrays to be editable by code later on, so using `get prop() {...}` doesn't work for that. In other languages, there are tricks you can do like declaring a const before defining it (as long as you do eventually define it) but Typescript doesn't seem to support anything like that as far as I've found. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this kind of definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no *good / elegant way*.

---

In your example, although the *variables* are contants, the *objects* themselves are mutable.

By abusing that fact, you can do this:

```js
export const foo: Bla {}
export const bar: Bla {}
export const baz: Bla {}

foo.prop = [bar, baz]
bar.prop = [foo, bar]
baz.prop = [bar, baz]
```

Of course, to do that, you'll have to define the property `prop` of `Bla` as optional, or something like that (you can also assign empty arrays to `prop`s in the literal and `.push` the values to them; that way you don't have to change your types).

---

However, this is rather a hack. The "proper" way would be to use getters (or lazy getters) and setters.

Comment: Dang, thanks. Looks like I have some structural reworking to do then.

Comment: Also make sure you never have to JSONify this data without overriding the `stringify` method (if you use the built-in). It will blow up on the circular references.

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty, but it works.

```
type Bla = { prop: [Bla, Bla] };

const emptyBla = undefined as any as Bla;
export const foo: Bla = { prop: [emptyBla, emptyBla] }
export const bar: Bla = { prop: [emptyBla, emptyBla] }
export const baz: Bla = { prop: [emptyBla, emptyBla] }

foo.prop = [bar, baz];
bar.prop = [foo, bar];
baz.prop = [bar, baz];
```

Typically you break these kind of cycles by a layer of indirection. For example instead of storing the references to the objects you store the identifiers of the objects and then store the objects separately in some central place.

I am not a fan of getters and setters because it can mislead the user of your class.

Comment: Dang, thanks. Looks like I have some structural reworking to do then.